# How do I generate a sitemap.xml file with sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sitemap, toctree

[Here](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/markup/toctree.html) it says: "The special entry name self stands for the document containing the toctree directive. This is useful if you want to generate a “sitemap” from the toctree." And I have been looking at this thred - [Using self to create a sitemap with toctree in sphinx seem broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126747/using-self-to-create-a-sitemap-with-toctree-in-sphinx-seem-broken). I can't seem to get this to work.

Is there anywhere that has a detailed example of a sitemap being generated by sphinx I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the sitemap generator in this theme with my own.
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle_sphinx_theme

```
# Import guzzle theme https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle_sphinx_theme
# Not actually using the theme but intead using the
# sitemap functionality and overriding the theme/templates in source/
html_translator_class = 'guzzle_sphinx_theme.HTMLTranslator'
html_theme_path = guzzle_sphinx_theme.html_theme_path()
html_theme = 'guzzle_sphinx_theme'
extensions.append("guzzle_sphinx_theme")
html_theme_options = {
    "base_url": "YOURSITEURL"
}
```

I'm overriding everything in my source directory I'm not using any other parts of the theme other than the sitemap generator. Pretty sloppy solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is four years old, so at that time maybe this plugin was not available. I just tried the [sphinx-sitemap](https://github.com/jdillard/sphinx-sitemap) plugin, and it worked for me.

The integration is easy:

```
pip install sphinx-sitemap
```

and then in your `config.py` set:

```
extensions = ['sphinx_sitemap']
html_baseurl = 'https://my-site.com/docs/'
```

And then generate the site normally. A sitemap.xml will apear at the base of your project. They also have some advanced functionality such as versioning and multi language (i haven't tried yet).